# How to create ArreyList in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

do you know someone explain how to make ArrayList in JavaFx and that listed in textArea with for loops, or a second loop.
Thanks.

Comment: ArrayList is just plain java, it has nothing to do with JavaFX. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example of creating an array list and then looping through it for its total length if that is what you are looking for.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public void arrayListTest() {
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add("Hello this is 0 in the ArrayList");
    al.add("G'Day this is 1 in the ArrayList");
    al.add("Auf Wiedersehen this in 2 in the ArrayList signing out");

    for (Integer i=0;i<al.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(al.get(i));
    }
}
```

This should output:

```
Hello this is 0 in the ArrayList
G'Day this is 1 in the ArrayList
Auf Wiedersehen this in 2 in the ArrayList signing out
```

For more information refer to the Oracle database on [ArrayLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)